# How does HBase mapreduce job communicate with server? (newbie question)

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am new to Hadoop and HBase and even though I've read allot, I still don't understand the basic hierarchy and workflow of map reduce job API.

By what I understand, I will need to use the java API to implement certain classes and pass them to hbase which will coordinate the splitting and distribution process. Is that correct?

If so, how does the application communicate with the server to pass the relevant code for the map reduce job? I have a missing link here....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just work through the [basic tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html), which should make things clear. I found the quickest way to get started was by playing with the [Cloudera VM](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM).

Also, I'm not sure about your reference to HBase; you should be passing Java classes to Hadoop, not HBase.

However, in an attempt to answer you question, Hadoop should be installed on all nodes in your cluster. The Hadoop framework will take care of farming the map and reduce tasks out to nodes.

Comment: Adrian, thanks. I read the tutorial and the book and many others. This is something that i think is so obvious that no one seems to mention.

Comment: I saw examples of executing the code throu eclipse and not only through Hadoop command line, soi I didnt understand how that works exactly.

Comment: You realise you need to run the mapreduce job directly on the Hadoop server?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about the Eclipse integration.

Comment: That what I thought, but look here http://sujee.net/tech/articles/hbase-map-reduce-freq-counter/

Comment: I understand. The author has installed Hadoop on his local machine and is using it for development. There is a section "Running this on a Hbase cluster (multi machines)" where the example is compiled into a jar, copied over to the server and run remotely.

Comment: So when he runs it locally, the API initiates the call to Hadoop, as if it was ran using the regular command line on server?

Comment: I haven't used the Eclipse integration, but I expect he has configured eclipse to call hadoop directly when "Run as" is selected. It's nothing to get hung-up on.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, now I understand completely. But one more thing, if HBase map reduce is actually hadoop's, then what is the difference between them and why do they call it HBase native map reduce?

Comment: This confused me for a second. I think it is just that there are "helper" classes for doing hadoop mapreduce jobs that use hbase. I.e. you are extending hbase classes which are then run on hadoop rather than having to implement your own stuff to deal with hbase tables.

Answer (score 3):

When you run your HBase MapReduce job, your classpath has to contain both the HBase and MapReduce configuration files. The configuration files will contain settings such as the location of the JobTracker, the HDFS NameNode, and the HBase master node. The runtime will then automatically pick up all these settings from the configuration files so that your job knows which servers to contact.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to execute a M/R job using HBase is the same way you execute a non-HBase m/r job:
${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop jar .jar  [args]

This copies your jar to all of the task trackers (via HDFS) so that they can execute your code.

With HBase you also will typically use the HBase utility:
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob

This uses built-in algorithms to split an HBase table (using the regions of the table) so that computation can be distributed over the m/r jobs.  If you want a different split, you have to modify the way splits are calculated, which means that you cannot use the built-in utility.

The other thing you can specify is conditions on the rows that are returned.  If you use a built-in scan condition, then you don't have to do anything special.  However, if you want to create a custom comparator, you have to make sure that the region servers have this code in their classpath so that they can execute it.  Before you go this route, examine the built-in comparators carefully, as they are quite powerful.